# skip rows in a loop that have line-through

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Background: I'm using a spreadsheet to create events in calendar to keep a schedule for my theater. Because our shows are constantly updating and shifting around I've opted to use an example I found here that deletes and rebuilds events each time based on their eventId, and it works great. The other element I implement is each night it does a check and adds a line-through and italics to any event that's past. I would love to adjust the function for creating events to skip anything with italics or line-through so past events stay unchanged.

TlDr:
How to skip rows that have "line-through" in my for loop?

Here's what I have now:

```
   /**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportPracticeEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var data = range.getValues();
  var strike = range.getFontLine();
  Logger.log(strike);
  var calId = "24thstreet.org_eri1dhhin8rnelpg2kuoacklnk@group.calendar.google.com"; //practice
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s) and rows with line-through
    if (range.getFontLine() === "line-through") { continue; };
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]);  // First column
    var type = row [1];
    var title = row[13];           // Fourteenth column
    var tstart = new Date(row[3]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[4]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var loc = "1117 w 24th Street, Los Angeles, CA 90007";
    var desc = row[14];
    var id = row[15];              // Sixteenth column == eventId actual
    // Check if event already exists, delete it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventById(id)
      event.deleteEvent();
      row[15] = '';  // Remove event ID    
      }
    catch (e) {
        // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
      }
    //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
    //var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
    //row[15] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
    //debugger;
    if (type == "NO ESR") {
      cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010"));
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date).getId();
      row[15] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID

    }

    else {
      cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
      row[15] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID

    }
     debugger;

    }
// Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
var id_data = data.map(function (row) {
  return [row[15]];      // keep only that column
});
sheet.getRange(1, 16, id_data.length, 1).setValues(id_data);  // write it in the sheet
}
```

My " if (range.getFontLine() === "line-through") { continue; }; " doesn't seem to do anything. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about modifying as follows? One line was added and one line was modified. The font line data is retrieved with the same range for `data`, and reflected to the for loop.

I understand that from your script, `row[15]` which is column "P" is the values which should search "line-through". Is my understanding correct?

#### Modified script :

```
var fontLines = range.getFontLines(); // <--- Added
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s) and rows with line-through
  if (fontLines[i][15] == "line-through") { continue; }; // <--- Modified
```

#### Note :

- I showed this modification part using a part of your script. If you are difficult to understand this, please tell me.

#### Reference :

- [getFontLines()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontLines())

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.